# How do I convert separate int values to hex byte array

Tags: c#, hex, byte, tcp

I need to do some (new to me) int/hex/byte work and I am struggling to get it right. The tcp server on the other side is expecting Little Endian.

I need to send a byte array consisting of HEX values.

`6000` needs to be sent as:

> `0x70, 0x17`

`19` needs to be sent as:

> `0x13, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00`

[image: parameters]

The resulting byte array should look like this.

```
**FROM THE MANUFACTURER**
Complete message should be: 

0x70, 0x17, 0x13, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x42, 0x0f, 0x00, 0xA0, 0x86, 0x01, 0x00, 0x04, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04
```

I can get the hex value of `6000` as `1770` by using: `.ToString("x4")`
I can get the hex value of `19` as `00000013` by using: `.ToString("x8")`

I have two questions:

1. This (to my knowledge) is Big Endian. Short from chopping the string and manually rewriting it to reverse it, is there a .net routine that can do this for me?
2. Once I have it reversed, how do I get

> `7017`

in a byte array of:

> `[0] = 0x70, [1] = 0x17`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in which format do you need it in the end? starting with 6000 it should endup in a `byte[] {0x70, 0x17}` ?

Comment: are you sending raw bytes? Then `BitConverter.GetBytes(value);` would by more suitable than strings. And once you have a byte array, just call `Array.Reverse(bytes);` to reverse your bytes.

Comment: @MongZhu and @fairtrax. Manufacturer message states final data on the wire should be a byte array that looks like: `0x70, 0x17, 0x13, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x42, 0x0f, 0x00, 0xA0, 0x86, 0x01, 0x00, 0x04, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04`

Comment: I was doing such staff in java with bit-wise operators, shifting each 8 bits of a number to the right, converting to byte etc, that was much more complicated :D but funny, just playing with bits.

Comment: do you send formatted strings, or bytes? `0x70, 0x17` etc is just human-readable form of the bytes, but the bytes "on the wire" take 1 byte per byte, instead of 4 (0x17 is 23 etc.) If you really format them and send a string separated by commas, use the code of Mong Zhu below.

Comment: @fairtrax it sounds like he really needs a byte array

Comment: To be quite honest. I am a bit out of my depth here. :-) The message above is what I received from the manufacturer. The data is not sent as comma seperated, the comma's are just in the mix to show how the data is broken up. I also thought sending HEX is the wrong approach, but the manufacturer message is confusing as it states the value of the final message to be sent as a byte array, should be as above.

Comment: what is the interface? CAN Bus? SerialPort? TCP-IP ? USB ?

Comment: TCP/IP. Here is/was my first attempt...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45195966/lapsnaper-tcp-connection-specification?noredirect=1#comment77361648_45195966

Comment: then use `BitConverter.GetBytes(value);`, reverse them to get little endian, and send to the tcp ip stream.

Comment: I have tried this, but what is confusing to me is the padding of the expected bytes length the server is expecting. On message ID for instance, how do I get it into 4 different bytes? (As the server expects it), using bitconverter?

Please excuse my questions if they sound very novice. I am trying to learn. ;-)

Comment: @LouisvanTonder [GetBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4(v=vs.110).aspx) always returns an array of 4 bytes length. I edited my post with a method, that can cut down the array to the length that you need. Have a look

Comment: according to your message format, your messageID requires 2 bytes. GetBytes(int) retrieves always 4 bytes, you can use any of them, as you want, like `bytes[0]` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [BitConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) class to achieve the conversion.
The result is actually already in the convention that you need. No Reversion is necessary

```
byte[] res6000 = BitConverter.GetBytes(6000);
byte[] res19 = BitConverter.GetBytes(19);

// TEST OUTPUT for example
Console.WriteLine(" 6000 -> : " + String.Join("", res6000.Select(x => x.ToString("X2"))));
Console.WriteLine("  19  -> : " + String.Join("", res19.Select(x=>x.ToString("X2"))));
```

Output:

> 6000 -> : 70170000
>     19  -> : 13000000

Here is a little method that does the job, with the amount of bytes that you desire:

```
public byte[] TransformBytes(int num, int byteLength)
{
    byte[] res = new byte[byteLength];

    byte[] temp = BitConverter.GetBytes(num);

    Array.Copy(temp, res, byteLength);

    return res;
}
```

Then you could call it and combine the result in a list like this:

```
List<byte> allBytesList = new List<byte>();

allBytesList.AddRange(TransformBytes(   6000, 2));
allBytesList.AddRange(TransformBytes(     19, 4));
allBytesList.AddRange(TransformBytes(1000000, 4));
allBytesList.AddRange(TransformBytes( 100000, 4));
allBytesList.AddRange(TransformBytes(      4, 1));

Console.WriteLine(" All -> : " + String.Join(" ", allBytesList.Select(x => x.ToString("X2"))));
```

Output:

> All -> : 70 17 13 00 00 00 40 42 0F 00 A0 86 01 00 04

The `List<byte>` can be easily converted in the end to an array:

```
byte [] b_array = allBytesList.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks a stack for this very detailed answer! It is appreciated. At least now the server is returning some data. On to the next challenge of reading said data. 

Thanks

Comment: @LouisvanTonder You are welcome. Good luck with the server chit-chat ;)